# Obtaining a specific implementation instance, based on a parameter

Tags: java, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, guice

I am using Guice, and I am in a situation, in which I need to obtain a specific implementation of a given interface, depending on a certain parameter. Unlike setter/controller injection, I would request the instance in a method, only knowing the value of the parameter when the method is being called.

I can solve my problem, using a classical factory object and inject a factory instance, where I would normally inject the implementation instance itself. I checked out Guice's providers, which looked promising at first, but seem to have no way of passing a parameter to the get() method.

Is this how you would approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Guice provide factory helper for the first approach called [Assisted Inject](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AssistedInject)

But, there is possibility to do it better with [Custom scopes](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/CustomScopes).

The idea is to `seed` the parameter that object injection is dependent on into Provider.

It would look like:

Module:

```
bind(CommandProperty.class).toProvider(ExchangeScope.<CommandProperty>seededKeyProvider()).in(ExchangeScope.class); //<< this is missing in tutorial
```

Scoped code:

```
scope.enter();
try {
  // explicitly seed some seed objects...
  scope.seed(Key.get(CommandProperty.class), commandPropertyInstance);

  // create and access scoped objects
  runnable.run();

} finally {
  scope.exit();
}
```

Provider:

```
  private Provider<CommandProperty> commandPropertyProvider;
  private Map<CommandProperty, Provider<Object>> objectProviderMap;

  @Inject
  public ObjectProvider(Provider<CommandProperty> commandPropertyProvider, Map<CommandProperty, Provider<Object>> objectProviderMap) {
    this.commandPropertyProvider = commandPropertyProvider;
    this.objectProviderMap = objectProviderMap;
  }

  @Override
  public CommandProperty get() {
    CommandProperty commandP = commandPropertyProvider.get();
    return objectProviderMap.get(commandP).get();
  }
```

As you can see `objectProviderMap` will come during runtime and can be injected. The difference is you get rid of factory and you can create object the constructor/setter way. The downfall is you have to maintain bigger code complexity. I would rather use it the core or framework like codebase not the application level.

Comment: I'd like to avoid introducing my classes to the notion of a Provider (if possible)

Comment: Well, then i can't imagine how to do it. The factory is only option.